# VueJS: V-Calendar change style from @dayclick function

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to change style of each day using @dayclick with v-calendar (not date picker) since there is no documentation how to modify a selected day object. https://vcalendar.io

[image]

Comment: You want to change the style of the selected days?

Comment: @Nathan a selected day when it's clicked  as focus state and it changes color from green to red